# Normalizr - How to generate slug/id related to parent entity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, normalizr

How can I assign id/slug related to the entity's parent using [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr)?

Example:

API Response for a user call:

```
{
  id: '12345',
  firstName: 'John',
  images: [
    {
      url: 'https://www.domain.com/image0',
      name: 'image0'
    },
    {
      url: 'https://www.domain.com/image1',
      name: 'image1'
    }
  ]
}
```

I could define my schemas in the following way:

```
const image = new Schema('images');
const user = new Schema('users');

user.define({
  images: arrayOf(image)
})
```

The problem is that images don't have an `id` property, so normalizr will not be able to distinguish them unless we provide an `id` property. Of course, we could do something like

```
const image = new Schema('images', { idAttribute: uuid.v4() });
```

and generate unique identifiers.

Suppose we receive a user update and an image's name has been updated. Because we generate unique identifiers in every normalization, we are not able to identify and update the existing image.

I need a way to reference the parent entity (user) in the image entity (either in its id/slug like `12345-image0`, `12345-image1` or as a separate property.

What would be the optimal way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

`idAttribute` can be a function that receives the entity, the parent and the key that references the slice of state:

```
const image = new Schema('images', {
  idAttribute: (entity, parent) => `${parent.id}-${entity.name}`
});
```

Answer (score 6):

## Problem

Using uuid the way you show will not work.

```
const image = new Schema('images', { idAttribute: uuid.v4() });
```

`uuid.v4()` returns a string, an acceptable value for `idAttribute` but now all your `images` will have the same uid. Not what you want.

Ideally this would work:

```
const image = new Schema('images', { idAttribute: () => uuid.v4() });
```

Unfortunately, `idAttribute` will be invoked multiple times, as mentioned [in this issue](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/issues/201). This will break any entity relations. In your example, the images will have different uids than what the user entity references them as.

example output:

```
users: {
  '12345': {
    id: '12345',
    firstName: 'John',
    images: [
      "cj20qq7zl00053j5ws9enz4w6",
      "cj20q44vj00053j5wauawlr4u"
    ],
  }
};
images: {
  cj20q44v100003j5wglj6c5h8: {
    url: 'https://www.example.org/image0',
    name: 'image0'
  },
  cj20q44vg00013j5whajs12ed: {
    url: 'https://www.example.org/image1',
    name: 'image1'
  }
};
```

## Solution

A work around for this is to mutate the input value in the `processStrategy` callback, giving it an `uid` attribute.

```
const getUid = value => {
  if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(value, 'uid')) value.uid = uuid.v4();
  return {...value};
};

const image = new Schema('images', { processStrategy: getUid, idAttribute: 'uid'});
```

You're mutating the value now, so that sucks, but the `idAttribute` option uses the input value, not the processed value.

Alternatively, you could mutate the value in the `idAttribute` callback, then you would not add the `uid` field to the output value.

*sidenote: I would recommend using the `cuid` npm package instead of `uuid`*

Comment: `processStrategy` doesn't have to mutate the value, you can return a new object with an id field.

Comment: the `idAttribute` parameter is not referencing the returned object, it references the original `value`. That is why I had to mutate the original value. (unless I'm mistaken but I recall checking this a few times, I also confirmed with paul armstrong)

Comment: You might be right, the `getId` function references the original `input`, rather than the `processedEntity` here: https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/blob/a20d535c0ddd21c95cf8498647fa8e060b5ed8a8/src/schemas/Entity.js#L61

Comment: And the relevant test: https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/blob/a20d535c0ddd21c95cf8498647fa8e060b5ed8a8/src/__tests__/index.test.js#L108