# Normalizr - is it a way to generate IDs for non-ids entity model?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, normalizr

I'm using `normalizr` util to process API response based on non-ids model. As I know, typically `normalizr` works with ids model, but maybe there is a some way to generate ids "on the go"?

My API response example:

```

```
// input data:
const inputData = {
  doctors: [
   {
    name: Jon,
    post: chief
   },
   {
    name: Marta,
    post: nurse
   },
   //....
}

// expected output data:
const outputData = {
  entities: {
   nameCards : {
    uniqueID_0: { id: uniqueID_0, name: Jon, post: uniqueID_3 },
    uniqueID_1: { id: uniqueID_1, name: Marta, post: uniqueID_4 }
   },
   positions: {
    uniqueID_3: { id: uniqueID_3, post: chief },
    uniqueID_4: { id: uniqueID_4, post: nurse }
   }
  },
  result: uniqueID_0
}
```

```

P.S.
I heard from someone about generating IDs "by the hood" in `normalizr` for such cases as my, but I did found such solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Normalizr - How to generate slug/id related to parent entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39681284/normalizr-how-to-generate-slug-id-related-to-parent-entity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/issues/256):

> Normalizr is never going to be able to generate unique IDs for you. We
>   don't do any memoization or anything internally, as that would be
>   unnecessary for most people.
>
> Your working solution is okay, but will fail if you receive one of
>   these entities again later from another API endpoint.
>
> My recommendation would be to find something that's constant and
>   unique on your entities and use that as something to generate unique
>   IDs from.

And then, as mentioned in the docs, you need to set `idAttribute` to replace 'id' with another key:

```
const data = { id_str: '123', url: 'https://twitter.com', user: { id_str: '456', name: 'Jimmy' } };

const user = new schema.Entity('users', {}, { idAttribute: 'id_str' });
const tweet = new schema.Entity('tweets', { user: user }, { 
    idAttribute: 'id_str',
    // Apply everything from entityB over entityA, except for "favorites"
    mergeStrategy: (entityA, entityB) => ({
      ...entityA,
      ...entityB,
      favorites: entityA.favorites
    }),
    // Remove the URL field from the entity
    processStrategy: (entity) => omit(entity, 'url')
});

const normalizedData = normalize(data, tweet);
```

**EDIT**

You can always provide unique id's using external lib or by hand:

```
inputData.doctors = inputData.doctors.map((doc, idx) => ({ 
  ...doc, 
  id: `doctor_${idx}`
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a processStrategy which is basically a function and in that function assign your id's there, ie. `value.id = uuid()`. Visit the link below to see an example  https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/issues/256